# Mocking angularjs http requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-e2e

So i have done quite a research already before asking this and none of them is what i want.

I have an app bootstrapped with angular module. The controller inside the module makes some http requests. Now i am unit testing my app for ui and i need to mock the http requests. All the mocking that i have read is done with jasmine, but i don't want to use it.

I want that whenever i open the app, all the requests get mocked. I have already tried angular mock and the backend mocks, none of them workes. And i dont want to prepopulate the scope elements because the code should be deployment ready.

Comment: You need to mock http requests, or server responses to those requests?

Comment: You could always set up a service that makes the http calls instead of making them directly from the controller. If you call the service from the controller then you can easily mock the service.

Comment: I need to mock the response

Comment: Yes you do. If the response is provided by an angular service that you define instead of $http then it will be easier for you to mock the response.

Comment: Need more information. You say that angular mocks doesn't work, but it does. I've used it on plenty of projects, so it sounds more like either you don't now how to use it or have an issue. What is it exactly you are doing that isn't working? If you inject the $httpBackend service and configure it, you can mock the requests as needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to mock your backend during development, just install `angular-mocks` in your main html file, add it up as a dependency in your application (`angular.module('myApp', ['ngMockE2E'])`) and then mock the requests you need to.

E.g.

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $httpBackend, $http) {
    $httpBackend.whenGET('test').respond(200, {message: "Hello world"});
    $http.get('test').then(function(response){
      $scope.message = response.message //Hello world
    })
  });
```

Be wary though, that adding the `ngMockE2E` will require you to set up your routes in case you do so through AngularJS routing.

E.g.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngMockE2E'])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  })
  .run(function($httpBackend){
    $httpBackend.whenGET('views/main.html').passThrough();
  })
```