# Combining GET and POST as get and save in AngularJS service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I've got a service that gets details for a certain user profile:

```
.factory('UserDetails', function($resource, $rootScope) {
    return $resource('../html/app/user_details.json', {}, {
        query:
        {
            method: 'GET',
            params: {},
            isArray: true
        }
    });
})
```

I'm mocking the non-existent back-end with a plain JSON file for now.
I also need to be able to update the user profile - so I need to write a POST request (probably to the same end-point).

In my controller I currently use:

```
UserDetails.get({}, function(data) {
    $scope.profile = angular.copy(data.user_details);        
});
```

It would be elegant to be able to write

```
UserDetails.save({$scope.profile}, function(data){ /* .. */});
```

Is there a way to extend my UserDetails service to achieve this? How would I have to modify the service declaration?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `angular-mock` for your purpouses.

See related [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877593/mocking-angularjs-http-requests)

Comment: Mocking is not the issue here, the issue is how do I combine GET and POST in the same service.